# Documentation on the _civicrm_api3_* _spec functions

Tags: api, extension, hooks

I have a working extension with a working API hook `civicrm_api3_contact_getclif($params)`, but I can't find the documentation for the `_spec` function beyond [the suggestion to have one](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/How+to+migrate+or+write+an+api)

I wrote this function and it appears to work (ie the params are appearing in the API explorer as required), but I suspect there is more to this function.

What else can I include in this function to provide more metadata about the API I am writing?

`function _civicrm_api3_contact_getclif_spec(&$spec) { 
  $spec['clif']['api.required'] = 1;

  $spec['length']['api.required'] = 1;

}`

Can anyone point me to the source file that calls the `*_spec()` function if there is no doco?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "hook"? And you can read the _spec but you cannot read the api method itself? In general the_spec method only describes the available params and the method named similarily w/o the _spec param does the work. Read it and there you go. And by the way, an "offset" param shouldn't exist, it's covered in the obligatory 'options' param...

Comment: oh right maybe it's not a hook per se, more some kind of meta-data supplier... thanks for the pointer on the offset - but I'm still having trouble finding the doco that summarises the functionality.. any clues

Comment: have edited the question to clarify. Thanks @nielo

Comment: Sorry dude, I just can't see any clarification. Reading your updated question I would answer: No, there isn't more to this function. And there is no core source file holding such methods. What about a 'grep -r civicrm_api3_contact_getclif <your extensions source>'?

Comment: sorry I'm not being clear. `_civicrm_api3_contact_getclif_spec` is a function I wrote and it is working - but the thing is I have no clue as to what else I can include in the function to provide better metadata on the API I am writing.

Comment: just edited my question again @nielo to (hopefully) clarify - many thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [api/v3/Generic.php's](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/api/v3/Generic.php#L57) civicrm_api3_generic_getfields method